# Using an amazon step function, how do I write a choice operator that references current time?

Tags: aws-step-functions

In the aws-step function [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html#amazon-states-language-choice-state-rules), it seems possible to write a 'choice' state comparing variables from the current state. However, is it possible to write a timestamp comparison referencing the current time?  For example, say I want a particular state to be enabled when the time in my state's `$.myTime` property is `TimestampGreaterThan` the `[current time]`. For example:

```
{
   "Variable": "$.myTime",
   "TimestampGreaterThan": "<the current time>",
   "Next": "MyTimeSpecificState"
}
```

Is it possible to reference the current time, or do I have to manually set that on the state in a separate task?

Answer (score 21):

Yes, it is currently (as of 2020) possible by using the **Context Object** ($$), here's how:

```
{
   "Variable": "$.myTime",
   "TimestampGreaterThan": "$$.State.EnteredTime",
   "Next": "MyTimeSpecificState"
}
```

Here's the link to the AWS Step Functions Developers Guide: [Context Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html).

Comment: Is it something that you guys have tested? The stepfunction does not allow me to use "TimestampGreaterThan": "$.anyDateTimeVariable". I am getting the following error message when updating my step function: 'SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: String does not match RFC3339 timestamp

Comment: In the meantime, I figured out the answer for my own question. Here is the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67878445/aws-step-function-choice-step-timestampequals-matching-with-multiple-input-v/67903798#67903798)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot directly reference the current timestamp in a State Choice comparison. There are couple of approaches to solve this.

- Instead of returning 'myTime', you can return the matched result with current timestamp from the previous task. (Preferred)
- Use a new task to return whether the myTime matches with the current timestamp and return the results.

Comment: Can you provide any example of how to do this? I was able to use a pass state to add the StartTime from the context object (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) but it is not in the RFC format needed for that condition. Seems annoying that they would provide it like that but not make it very useful.