# AWS Step function - choice step - TimestampEquals matching with multiple input variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, timestamp, matching

I have been trying to create a step function with a choice step that acts as a rule engine. I would like to compare a date variable (from the stale input JSON) to another date variable that I generate with a lambda function.

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) does not go into details about the Timestamp comparator functions, but I assumed that it can handle two input variables. Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
{
  "Variable": "$.staleInputVariable",
  "TimestampEquals": "$.generatedTimestampUsingLambda"
}
```

Here is the error that I am getting when trying to update(!!!) the stepFunction. I would like to highlight the fact that I don't even get to invoking the stepFunction as it fails while updating the function.

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid State Machine Definition: 'SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: String does not match RFC3339 timestamp at ..... (Service: AWSStepFunctions; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidDefinition; Request ID: 97df9775-7d2d-4dd2-929b-470c8s741eaf; Proxy: null)" (RequestToken: 030aa97d-35a5-a6a5-0ac5-5698a8662bc2, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

The stepfunction updates without the Timestamp matching, therefore, I suspect this bit of code.. Any guess?

EDIT (08.Jun.2021):

> A comparison – Two fields that specify an input variable to compare,
> the type of comparison, and the value to compare the variable to.
> Choice Rules support comparison between two variables. Within a Choice
> Rule, the value of Variable can be compared with another value from
> the state input by appending Path to name of supported comparison
> operators.
> Source: [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html)

It clearly states that two variables can be compared, but to no avail. Still trying :)

Comment: Yeah, if I replace it with "TimestampEquals": "2016-03-14T01:59:00Z", it works. The string must conform with the RFC3339 profile of ISO 8601. Not taking any other format!

Comment: I know that it works with static strings, but I can't have "magic strings" in this case.. I have to compare a variable to another variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I explained the problem to one of my peers, I realised that the AWS documentation mentions a **Path** postfix (which I confused with the $.). This Path needs to be added to the operatorName.

The following code works:

```
{
  "Variable": "$.staleInputVariable",
  "TimestampEqualsPath": "$.generatedTimestampUsingLambda"
}
```

Again, I would like to draw your attention to the "**Path**" word. That makes the magic!

Comment: And in Workflow Studio, note that you must select Timestamp Variable not Timestamp Constant (same with Number Variable/Timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you indeed found a way around your initial challenge from the thread linked below.

[Using an amazon step function, how do I write a choice operator that references current time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460864/using-an-amazon-step-function-how-do-i-write-a-choice-operator-that-references)

However, I thought you wanted to compare `$.staleInputVariable` to the current timestamp and I wince to think you had to configure a lambda function (and test it!) to do only that.

If so, you could have achieved that simply by using the [Context Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) or `$$.`:

```
{
  "Variable": "$$.State.EnteredTime",
  "TimestampEqualsPath": "$.staleInputVariable"
}
```